# Inserting GeoPoint in Elasticsearch is not working

Tags: json, elasticsearch, maps, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I am sending Geo data in lat-lon pairs (as a GeoPoint) into Elasticsearch 6.3. But it stores it as a String and not GeoPoint.

1. Is there any plugin required for ELK to accept data as GeoPoint?
2. What is the deal with GeoHashing? I have tried that too with sending data encoded as GeoHashes using the following libraries:
   https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java
   and
   https://github.com/Factual/beercode-open/blob/master/formats/Geohash.java
   Didn't work.
3. I have also tried working with all kinds of sample data like flights, logs and this too: 
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html

Comment: Can you share your mappings? I thinck you didnot explicitly set the field as a "location" (or you just let elasticautomap for you). Documentation link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

Comment: This is how it looks in Discover tab: {
  "lon": 9.1757,
  "lat": 48.77564
}

Comment: What is GeoHash and GeoPoint really? The sample data in Kibana shows DestLocation  and OriginLocation as map types or Geo(Point) types. What's the way to insert it using a Java program. It seems to not so easily insert data in GeoPoint type. Plus, how do GeoPoint become a GeoHash?

Comment: You have to say to elasticsearch (using mapping) that your X field is a location field (link in my first post). After that it will be possible to index your geopoint field in the format you want.